# Error: "Unfortunately, Gmail has stopped", on arrival of an email

Tags: gmail, system-error

Every time I receive an email, this message shows up on my Droid

> Unfortunately, Gmail has stopped.

How can I remedy this situation?

Comment: did you check out our [tag:gmail] tag wiki? It has information documenting these issues and possible ways to correct them.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest various things which would most probably resolve the issue.

1. Uninstall updates to the app and update it again.
2. Update the app to the latest version (if you've not updated it).
3. Try to use the previous build (stock build) by uninstalling the recent update. And, check whether the problem has been resolved.

   - If you've rooted the device, the above three would also be applicable
4. At last, Factory Reset is the option.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this bug on my Nexus for about 2 days. Absolutely infuriating. It was stopping me from accessing phone settings because when the error message described above came up, which it did almost all the time, the screen closed.

Opening Gmail settings seemed to definitely trigger an instant error message every time. I tried a few things.

I had never had the Google/android "inbox"app on this phone. I installed it in addition to my Gmail app. Instantly, the bug stopped. This was a really debilitating problem and I'm glad to have chanced on a solution that works for my phone!

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else who has this problem, wait until you have a notification for two new emails, then click the notification and you will be asked which app you would like to use, it wouldn't ask for me if it was just one email I would just get the error every time.

Comment: This doesn't sound very similar to the OP's problem.